# Taking raw pictures from the camera

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-camera, android-camera2

So, I'm trying to take a picture from the back camera of the phone with flash but seems like the camerakit library returns a bytes array when captureImage is called and,

I'm not sure if they are jpeg or raw bytes (what I want), the other thing I tried is use camera2 API but looks complicated (not sure if is the right approach also) and I could not find a good tutorial in raw format, just jpeg.

Could someone help me with a tutorial, example, or recommendation to proceed?

Comment: Try this vedio: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32RG4lR0PMQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample project see: [Raw-Dumper](https://github.com/fkeglevich/Raw-Dumper)

Answer (score -1):

Taking photo with camera intent give as result a byte data.

Luckily convert from byte to bitmap is nothing hard.

**Start camera intent**

```
private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
        takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        }
    }
}
```

**Get result after taking picture**

```
  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val bitmap = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

NOTE:

```
imageView = setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

imageView is mine imageView in layout

reference: 
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

Comment: If you put a down at least say why

Answer (score -1):

(updated path since it was broken)

https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/Camera2Basic is an official camera2 sample for capturing JPEG or DNG (RAW) buffers.